# Swift Displaying jpg picture from viewController

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiimage

I'm new to programming in swift and I'm trying to make a simple app. So basically in ViewController.swift, I have a function that returns a UIImage and the reason why I need a function is because it displays an image with a specified text centred in it and it converts this whole thing into a UIImage. My function prototype looks like this:

```
func generateImageWithText(text: String) -> UIImage
```

And i call it like this in viewDidLoad():

```
generateImageWithText(text: "Hello")
```

So the warning i'm getting is "Result of call to 'generateImageWithText(text:)' is unused"....I understand that it is unused because it just returns an image without displaying it on the app. How would i display this image?

Any help would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there!
First assign the results to a variable:

```
let image = generateImageWithText(text: "Hello")
```

Then create an ImageView, using that image.

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
```

add this view to your view controller's main view:

```
self.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Once you've done this, you'll need to fine tune it to get the proper size/aspect, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is declared as returning UIImage, but you are not assigning the return value to any variable or property.
You can assign it to variable:

```
let image = generateImageWithText(text: "Hello")
```

Or if you want it to appear on the screen you should add it as a subview. If your function is as you declared inside a class that is UIViewController, than you can do it this way:

```
self.view.addSubview(UIImageView(image: generateImageWithText(text: "Hello")))
```

You cannot display UIImage directly on a screen.
`UIKit` provides `UIImageView` for that purpose - wrapping up your image with that class will allow you to put it directly on a screen.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to wrap the `UIImage` in a `UIImageView`, and then add it to the view controller's main view:

```
    // Create image view
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image);

    // Set imageView's position / size / frame properties as desired

    // Add to view controller's main view
    self.view.addSubview(imageView);
```